# Data set on trust in the Internet of Things?

Tags: data-request, survey, internet-of-things

I've looked everywhere for a data set on trust in the Internet of Things (IoT) and found nothing.

The articles I've read either didn't mention the data sets used or the data sets were not public. I even emailed two publishers for their data set and they didn't help me.

Does anyone know of a good source for open data sets on trust in IoT?

Comment: I think you'd rather turn to IOT stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

Trustworthiness is a very vague term and I don't know what kind of trustworthiness you are interested in. I will give you two examples I came across in the last few years.

1. We can use data to test if can trust other members of the group. For example, are civil servants upholding the law and doing their work correctly. In this [blog](http://iquantny.tumblr.com/post/144197004989/the-nypd-was-systematically-ticketing-legally),   Ben Wellington showed that thousands of parking tickets in New York City were issued to legally parked cars. He managed to expose Police department mistakes by analyzing open data provided by New York City. The data used in his work should be available [here](https://opendata.cityofnewyork.us/).
2. The second example I came across is much more interesting. In short, can we trust the sources gathering information in our data set? A group of scientist ran into a problem when they were trying to determine noise pollution in a city by asking citizens to participate in the sensing process. Such data gathering scheme, in which volunteers gather data, is known as participatory sensing. In this case, participants installed an application that measured noise intensity on their smartphone. In such a scheme, it is very easy for anyone to contribute the data.  However, it is also easy for the user to intentionally or unintentionally collect faulty measurements. Check this [site](http://www.noisetube.net/) and their API to get to the data. You can also find a list of publications where the issue of trustworthiness is mentioned. Furthermore,  there is one that is not on the list on the website but I think it could be related to your work. Try to find paper entitled: "Are you contributing trustworthy data?: the case for a reputation system in participatory sensing ".

Are any of the above examples, an example of what you are interested in? Maybe to you, trustworthiness has an entirely different meaning.

Kind regards
JH